# Mule EE jars command populate_m2_repo needs %MULE_HOME% env variable set in windows

Tags: mule, devkit

When running populate_m2_repo C:\Users\me.m2\repository I get asked for %MULE_HOME% to be set. Typically on my computer I have more than one standalone version available for testing so its inconvenient to keep changing this variable every time a new standalone comes out.

Can someone explain why populate_m2_repo needs %MULE_HOME% to be set?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since mule 3.1.0 it is recommended not to set system wide the %MULE_HOME%, since the mule.bat script set it for you when not available.

That said the populate_m2_repo needs it to know where to find the artifact that need to be installed.

HTH

Comment: so I was just running it from the /bin dir so I thought it could just use the PWD as m-home